# Cannot seem to read an external file from jar when on linux

Tags: java, linux

Following code works fine on windows:

```
private static Properties getProps() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    File externalFile = new File("myProp.properties");

    if(externalFile.exists()) //if an external property file exists within the same path it is prioritized
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(externalFile));
    else{
        properties.load(CommandUtil.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/localpath/default.properties"));
    }
    return properties;
}
```

if myProp.properties exists within the same folder of the .jar, then this property file is read, otherwise default .properties file contained inside of the .jar itself will be taken.

When I move this program on a linux system it does not work anymore: even though there is a .properties file beside the .jar this is just ignored.
Why is that?

Comment: I suspect it's because of the forward slash in the beginning of your path - Linux is probably interpreting that as going to the root path of your entire machine and not just the jar (whereas Windows has no `/` path so it just interprets it as the top of the jar itself). What happens if you instead use a path relative to your `CommandUtil` class, assuming it's in the same jar as your properties file? E.g., prefix your path with as many `../` sequences as there are folders in the package hierarchy of `CommandUtil`.

Comment: The file will be resolved relative to the process' current working directory, not the directory with the jar. Maybe the way you invoke the program results in a different working directory on Windows and Linux?

Comment: Mmm...I don't like the idea of prefixing ../ because, even if it works, it will be pretty dependent on the specific location. No, I am invoking the program in the exact same way